# Angle from cross product and dot product formula not the same

Tags: vectors

Why is that the angle from my cross product formula not equal to the angle I get from my dot product formula considering the same set of vectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: So how exactly do "your formulae" read?